# 'TotalMilliseconds' in .NET Micro Framework

Tags: c#, .net, .net-micro-framework

I'm a Java developer and recently started on a [Netduino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netduino) hobby project. I have encountered a strange problem. My compiler tells me that there is no such thing as `TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds`.

Is it true, that TotalMilliseconds is something only the desktop version of .NET contains?

Comment: What is the EXACT error message you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't exist in the .NET Micro Framework.  Use this instead:

```
double totalMilliseconds = theTimeSpan.Ticks / 10000.0;
```

Comment: This truncates two a whole number, of course. The behavior of `TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds` is more like `double totalMilliseconds = theTimeSpan.Ticks / 10000.0;`.

Answer (score 3):

It is true. The `TotalMilliseconds()` property **does not exist** in the .NET Micro Framework. See [MSDN reference for Timespan in Desktop Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.TimeSpan_properties.aspx) vs. [MSDN reference for Timespan in Micro Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee436648.aspx).